# 'this' keyword within anonymous function

Tags: javascript, this, anonymous-function

Can someone tell me what object `this.onSubmit` is referring to in the following code?

```
(function () {
    var _d = vjo.dsf.EventDispatcher;
    var _r = vjo.Registry;

    function $1(p0) {
        return function (event) {
            return this.onSubmit(p0, event);
        };
    };
})();
```

I apologise if there is not enough context attached to this example.

Comment: but the breakpoint / debug / watch

Comment: MDN's documentation is great: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks for the link, it does appear to tell me everything I need to know about 'this'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is dynamically set. So to know its value, you need to know how the function is being called/used.

So the generic answer would be that `this` is referring to whatever was set as the `this` value of the execution context.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever object is being bound when the function is run.

Example:

```
(function() {
    ....
    function $1(p0) {
         return function (event) {
            return this.onSubmit(p0, event);
        };
    };

    var testObj = {
        foo: 'bar',
        onSubmit: function(x,y) { console.log(x,y); }
    };

    var func = $1('moep');

    func.call(testObj, 'hrhr'); // logs >> moep, hrhr
```

Comment: That's not very precis, what if it is not bound to an object?

Comment: It's always bound to an object. If not explicitly then implicitly to `window`. You knew that, right?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be bound to an object. If the code isn't in strict mode, a primitive will indeed be converted to its object wrapper type, or to `window` if `null` or `undefined`, but in strict mode, whatever value is given will be used in its given state with no conversion.

Comment: Actually, the only time when a function is bound is when you use `.bind`. At any other time, `this` is determined dynamically upon execution. I mean, consider a function `foo` and `bar.baz = foo; foo(); bar.baz()`. There is only one function (`foo`) but `this` will refer to different objects. It's not bound to a specific value.

Comment: @FelixKling: IMO, it's not unreasonable to describe `this` as being "bound" to its value for the duration of the function call. This answer does state "bound when the function is run". I don't think it's suggesting that it is permanently bound for all invocations.

Comment: @user1689607: Ah, I somehow must have overlooked that part. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Here it will be the window object. You can confirm this by adding `console.log(this)` on the line before.

Comment: There's no way to know that from the given code. Remember `this` is in the innermost function, which is being returned. So whatever invokes the outer function will get that returned function and invoke it at some point. So the `this` value will depend on how the function was invoked.

Comment: True, I suppose all we can say from the code example is that the line won't get called, since `$1` is unused.